# Why does putting the first line of the expression on the same line as let not compile?

Tags: syntax, f#

In F# the following statement will fail with the following errors

```
let listx2 = [1..10]
    |> List.map(fun x -> x * 2)
    |> List.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x)
```

> Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.
>
> Unexpected infix operator in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

However the following will compile

```
let listx2 = 
    [1..10]
    |> List.map(fun x -> x * 2)
    |> List.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x)
```

I also noticed that this compiles but has a warning

```
let listx2 = [1..10] |>
    List.map(fun x -> x * 2) |>
    List.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x)
```

> Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (10:18). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.

What is the difference between the first two statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have

```
 let listx2 = [1..10]
```

you are implicitly setting the indent level of the next line to be at the same character as the `[`. As given by the following rule for offside characters from the spec:

> Immediately after an = token is encountered in a Let or Member context.

So in the first example, the `|>` is indented less than `[` so you get an error, but in the second they are the same, so it all works.

I am not quite sure why moving the `|>` to the end of the line only gives a warning though.

Comment: For the eol `|>`: I think a line that ends with an operator implicitly continues on the next line, regardless of its indentation.